# Visual Studio Exceptions Always Break at One Level Up

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception, break

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Professional. I've set my project in Debug mode. However, every time when an exception occurs, instead of breaking at where the exception happens, it always breaks at one level up.

For example, If I have a dialog named dlgShowMe and it is called from a file named Main.cs with a line like this: dlg.ShowDialog().

If an exception happens inside dlgShowMe, say at its event handler with a statement: p.x = 0; where p is null.

Visual Studio always breaks at Main.cs at the line dlg.ShowDialog(), instead of where the exception happens: p.x = 0;

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Is the code that's throwing the exception a part of your project, or is merely referenced by it? If it is referenced, do you have the 'Enable Just My Code' option selected under Debugging/General?

Comment: It is part of my project. Both calling routine and the called dialog are in the same project.

Comment: The dialog might be in the same project, but is the implementation of ShowDialog? I’d recommend you check the debugger settings and disable just my code if it’s enabled. There’s also an option for debugging framework code, which you may want to select.

Comment: "just my code" is already disabled. Everything is within the same project, there is nothing referenced from outside.